# Migrating Classic Dev Mode to Super Dev Mode using GWT 2.5.1

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I find lot of stackoverflow question related to this [How to migrate a a custom sublass of GWT DevMode to GWT 2.7.0 Super dev mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091786/how-to-migrate-a-a-custom-sublass-of-gwt-devmode-to-gwt-2-7-0-super-dev-mode) but unable to solve my issue.I am migrating `classic dev mode` to `super dev mode` using `GWT 2.5.1`.I have lot of dependency maven project which is included in `User Entries` under `Classpath` tab .Also i added `com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer` as main class and `gwt-codeserver-2.5.1` jar under `Classpath` tab.While launching the apps its getting complied but when i change some think in code and relaunch it again(by removing `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` from URL) its not compiling the code(changes are not taking).In console,under `source->localhost:9876->dev_mode_on.js` `dev_mode_on.js` only exist others files are not there.Any help?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333050/116472 ?

Comment: Thanks Thomas..I will try this and update you